# The result is wrong after converting hex to float

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I am trying to convert Hex `4991a480` to float using Python 3.6

```
>>> struct.unpack('!f',bytes.fromhex("4991a480"))
(1193104.0,)
```

But it doesn't work correctly.

The result I want to get is 1.1931e+06. I used a conversion website, and it gave the result I was expecting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The result is not wrong, is just displayed in a different format. What you are looking for is called scientific notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the same thing, you just need to format it ([[Python 3]: Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)) to the *exponent notation* ([[Wikipedia]: IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)):

> ```
> >>> import struct
> >>> unpacked = struct.unpack("!f", bytes.fromhex("4991a480"))
> >>> unpacked
> (1193104.0,)
> >>> print("{:e}".format(unpacked[0]))
> 1.193104e+06
> ```

Note that [[Python 3]: struct.**unpack**(*format, buffer*)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) returns a *tuple*.

Answer (score 2):

The value which printed is actually the answer you expected, written in long-form notation instead of scientific notation. There is not a problem here.

See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) for more on scientific notation.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful to me!!